# how to block urls that end with ?print

Tags: joomla2.5

I am using joomla 2.5 and k2 as a content manager. I have 1745 URLs that includes `&print=1` in the end, i want to block them all from being indexed using robot.txt. 
exp : `http://tounes24.com/a-propos.html?tmpl=component&print=1`.  should i repeat this 1745 times:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: http://tounes24.com/a-propos.html?tmpl=component&print=1
```

how can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards in robot.txt. This should work -

```
Disallow: /*print=1
```